# Multiple requests are made to server on single click of link

Tags: sql, asp.net, iis, browser

I am facing an issue that some time occur on Production server only. The problem is, sometimes if user clicks on a link button the browser sends 2 requests for same.

I found [this link](http://geek.starbean.net/?p=393) (which describes the issue).

Code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPreview" runat="server" OnClientClick="ShowPreviewPopupMain(); return false;" >Preview</asp:LinkButton>
<script>
    function ShowPreview() {
        try {
            // Some code here....
            $("#btnPostBack").click();
        }
        catch (err) { }
    }
 </script>
```

On server side I saved the entry for each click with Date Time and it showed that some times 2 entries are made simultaneously. Which results in insertion of 2 duplicate records in database. I have implemented the logic to prevent the user to click more time on link while it process.

However, I couldn't simulate this on local environment.

For temporary basis I have modified the Database stored procedure to prevent duplicate entries in table. But I need to prevent the duplicate request just to secure the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

Check if IsPostBack property helps for your problem.

[Page.IsPostBack Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: thanks for comment, but it's postback request initiated by a linkbutton on page, but some times it is initiated 2 times, sply. when server takes more time to respond or fail to respond. I guess.